# Index error trying to deduplicate a list only using if and for

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

My goal is to write a program that removes duplicated elements from a list – E.g., [2,3,4,5,4,6,5] →[2,3,4,5,6] without the function set (only if and for)

At the end of my code I got stuck. I have tried to change everything in the if statement but it got me to nowhere, same error repeating itself here:

```
n=int(input('enter the number of elements in your list   '))  
mylist=[]            

for i in range (n):   
         for j in range (n):  
                  ele=input('  ')  
                  if mylist[i]!=mylist[j]: ***here is the error exactly , I dont really understand what does the out-of-range above problem have to do with the if statement right here***   
                     mylist.append(ele)   
print(mylist)
```

However, I changed nearly everything and I still got the following error:

```
if mylist[i]!=mylist[j]:  
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Why does this issue keep coming back? ps: I cant use the function set because I am required to use if and for only

Comment: Can we use a dict? They can't contain duplicate keys, just like a set.

Comment: As a general note, please try to standardise your indentation. Most Python developers use 4 spaces at every level of indentation (although occasionally you do see 2), but whatever you do use, use it consistently.

Comment: The "IndexError: list index out of range" means your list doesn't have that many items.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this all with a list comprehension that checks if the value has previously appeared in the list slice that you have already looped over.

```
mylist = [1,2,3,3,4,5,6,4,1,2,4,3]
outlist = [x for index, x in enumerate(mylist) if x not in mylist[:index]]
print(outlist)
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

In case you're not familiar with list comprehensions yet, the above comprehension is functionally equivalent to:

```
outlist = []
for index, x in enumerate(mylist):
    if x not in mylist[:index]:
        outlist.append(x)
print(outlist)
```

Comment: Making a new slice for each element is not very efficient.

Answer (score 2):

A set would be more efficient, but

```
>>> def dedupe(L):
...     seen = []
...     return [seen.append(e) or e for e in L if e not in seen]
...
>>> dedupe([2,3,4,5,4,6,5])
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

This is not just a toy solution. Because sets can only contain hashable types, you might really have reason to resort to this kind of thing. This approach entails a linear search of the seen items, which is fine for small cases, but is slow compared to hashing.

It still may be possible to do better than this in some cases. Even if you can't hash them, if you can at least sort the seen elements, then you can speed up the search to logarithmic time by using a binary search. (See [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html)).